# Shared memory data structure having pointer

Tags: pointers, shared-memory

Hi I am trying to use shared memory IPC for communicating between a processes. However, shmat is returning the starting of shared memory address when I try to use it for assigning a pointer to a data structure. My code is below

```
#define SHM_SIZE 10240
struct myds {
 int ind;
 char *data[1];
};
int main()
{

    key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65);
    struct myds *nums;

    int shmid = shmget(key,SHM_SIZE,0666|IPC_CREAT);

    char *shm_addr = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0);
    int *count = (int *) shm_addr;
    *count = 5;
    nums = (struct myds *)((void *)shm_addr + sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < *count; i++) {
         nums[i].ind = i;
    }
    
    char *t = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0);
    printf("%d\n", *count);
    sprintf(t, "check- 112\0");
    nums[0].data[0] = t;
    printf("Data written in memory:");

    getc(stdin);
    printf("%d\n", *count);

    shmdt(shm_addr);
    shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Last print of *count should print 5 but instead print something different and very large value. Which seems like an effect of sprintf(t, "check- 112\0"). Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I tried using a `newshmid` created via `shmget(key,1000,0666|IPC_CREAT)` but even then I am not getting the correct answer. I am trying to pass array of strings to another process using shared memory. Currently I am using a array of size 1 just to test how to accomplish this thing.

Comment: You don't need to allocate another block of shared memory, you already have one that you can use, you are just not using it *correctly*.

Comment: I tried that as well using `char *base_buf = (char *) ((void *)shm_addr + sizeof(int) + *count * sizeof(struct myds));` and assigning it to `nums[0].data[0]=base_buf` but thats not working in another process. It is giving segmentation fault in another process when I map the memory and try accessing it via `nums[0].data[0]`.  However I can access `nums[0].ind`. Thank you for helping me out here.

Comment: Then use offsets instead of pointers for the `data[]` array.  I have posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` and `t` point to the same memory address.  When `sprintf()` writes new data to that address via `t`, it overwrites the value being read via `*count`.  That is why you get garbage from `*count` after `sprintf()`.

It looks like you are trying to write your `sprintf()` data to memory pointed at by `nums[0].data[0]`, but you haven't actually set `data[0]` to point anywhere meaningful.  The starting address returned by `shmat()` is the wrong address to store in `data[0]`.

Since you are allocating a very large memory block, much more than an array of 5 `myds` structs actually needs, you can point `data[0]` to memory that follows the last allocated `myds` struct in the array.

Try something more like this:

```c
#define SHM_COUNT 5

struct myds {
    int ind;
    char* data[1];
};

int main()
{
    key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65);
    struct myds *nums;

    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int) + (sizeof(struct myds) * SHM_COUNT) + 11, 0666|IPC_CREAT);

    char *shm_addr = (char*) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    int *count = (int *) shm_addr;
    *count = SHM_COUNT;

    nums = (struct myds *)(shm_addr + sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < SHM_COUNT; i++) {
        nums[i].ind = i;
    }

    char *t = (char*) (nums + SHM_COUNT);
    printf("%d\n", *count);
    sprintf(t, "check- 112\0");

    for(int i = 0; i < SHM_COUNT; i++) {
        nums[i].data[0] = t;
    }

    printf("Data written in memory:");

    getc(stdin);
    printf("%d\n", *count);

    shmdt(shm_addr);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Then the other process can simply use the `char*` pointer stored in `nums[i].data[0]` to access the string for each `nums[]` element.

If you want to add different strings for each `nums[]` element, simply allocate enough shared memory to hold all of the strings, and then point `nums[i].data[0]` accordingly within that memory.

---

**UPDATE**: If storing `char*` pointers doesn't work for you, then store offsets instead, eg:

```c
#define SHM_COUNT 5

struct myds {
    int ind;
    size_t data_offset[1];
};

int main()
{
    key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65);
    struct myds *nums;

    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int) + (sizeof(struct myds) * SHM_COUNT) + 11, 0666|IPC_CREAT);

    char *shm_addr = (char*) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    int *count = (int *) shm_addr;
    *count = SHM_COUNT;

    nums = (struct myds *)(shm_addr + sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < SHM_COUNT; i++) {
        nums[i].ind = i;
    }

    char *t = (char*) (nums + SHM_COUNT);
    printf("%d\n", *count);
    sprintf(t, "check- 112\0");

    for(int i = 0; i < SHM_COUNT; i++) {
        nums[0].data_offset[0] = (t - shm_addr);
    }

    printf("Data written in memory:");

    getc(stdin);
    printf("%d\n", *count);

    shmdt(shm_addr);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Then the other process can simply add `nums[i].data_offset[0]` to their local `shm_addr` address to access the string for each `nums[]` element.